# Show loading image after clicking submit button magento prototype

Tags: magento-enterprise, prototype-js, form-validation

I want to show loading image after clicking the submit button using prototype. I want loading image appear after successful validation. I used this code

```
var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
dataForm.submit = function(button, url) { 
    if (this.validator.validate()) { 
        //image code                 
        document.getElementById('processing').style.display = 'block';
    }
}.bind(dataForm);
```

Code flow doesn't go inside `dataForm.submit = function(button, url) { .. }`.
Can anyone told me how to do it using prototype?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One of them is to override `submit` method of `VarienForm` class:

```
VarienForm.prototype.submit = VarienForm.prototype.submit.wrap(function($super, url) {
    // your action here
    // ..

    // then call parent method
    $super(url);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your answer.
I used this code to get it work

$('submitbt').observe('click', function(){
    if (dataForm.validator.validate()) { 
     
    // your code
         }
      }.bind(dataForm));

Comment: @Vaibhav Shahu - That worked brilliantly, most impressed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, might be useful to others:

In Block/Adminhtml/blockname/Edit/Tab/Form.php I have added following Script in setAfterElementHtml() function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function(){
   var dataForm = new varienForm("edit_form", true);
   jQuery("body").on("click", ".generateReport", function(){
   if (dataForm.validator.validate()) { 
       jQuery(this).prop("disabled", true);
       jQuery("#loading-mask").show(); 
   }
   });
});
```